# making GoogleMap available offline

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm working on an Android app that uses [MapBoxOfflinetileProvider](https://github.com/cocoahero/android-gmaps-addons) to let user access maps offline. I'm adding the offline tiles to a GoogleMap object, as recommended in the documentation, and it works fine offline as long as the user has opened the map activity at least once with an internet connection. If the user installs the app, shuts off the internet connection, and then goes to the activity, however, the GoogleMap object is never instantiated and nothing is displayed. As a workaround, I am now instantiating and then removing a GoogleMap object when the user first opens the app. This seems to work fine, but I want to know if anyone has any better solutions or sees any downsides to my approach.

The code I am using, placed in the onCreate method of the app's initial "switchboard" activity is:

```
if(!PropertyHolder.isGoogleMapsOfflineReady() && Util.isOnline(context)){
// do initial connect to Google Play Services so that map works offline
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());
if (status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if(supportMapFragment != null){
    GoogleMap gm = supportMapFragment.getMap();
    if(gm != null){
        PropertyHolder.setGoogleMapsOfflineReady(true);
        gm = null;
    }
    }
}
}
```

where `R.id.map` is a reference to the ID of a map fragment hidden in the activity's layout.